# Is jupyter appmode with the "Edit App" button disabled secure?

Tags: security, jupyter-notebook

Scenario: I use `ipywidgets` and `appmode` in a jupyter notebook to develop a web app. I want to expose this to the public (let's say a Docker container running the jupyter server, living on an AWS instance or whatever).

If I make the server settings such that the "Edit App" button for the appmode view is disabled, is that all that's required to prevent folks from accessing the notebook source and running arbitrary python code? Could they still go to the original notebook by changing the url? I found the documentation slightly unclear on that.

Comment: Interesting question.  Chrome inspector (<ctrl> <option> i) -> sources, seems to only expose ui js code.    Even after removing the app-mode param from the url, it displays app-mode. That behavior implies to me that the user will be in app-mode until the kernel is instructed to revert to edit mode via edit button?

Comment: Interesting point to look at the page code. If I _don't_ disable the "Edit App" button and inspect what that button does, it's just simple java script that changes the url. Apparently the switch between app mode and notebook mode is done by just changing from `baseurl/apps/app_notebook.ipynb` to `baseurl/notebooks/app_notebook.ipynb` so I guess if the user can just change that in the browser, they can see the notebook. Unless I can somehow specifically disable that url.

Comment: We use Jupyter in similar way; rapid deployment of web based tools, which is kind of 'off label' (as opposed to stepping users through the call stack). The only code we have in each notebook is an import statement for external .py modules.  We do it for several reasons. It helps with "Trust issues" and let's us place code upstream from the notebook.  Even in edit mode the most a user could do in a cell is work with objects created externally - but not change the core code. Prolly TMI.

Comment: But if they are in a notebook, can't they still run arbitrary python code, including the execution of command line commands?

Comment: Yes but that’s a feature in our case. We use it internally on JHub and each user runs the collection of notebooks on their own unique path. Notebooks go back to factory settings every time they log out of Jupyter.

Comment: I see. In my case I really don't want the user to have any access to the underlying python code and no way to get any way whatsoever to execute anything at all on the jupyter notebook server.

Answer (score 1):

Im in your same situation @lagerbaer. I decided to look elsewhere for the solution since appmode is not a real security layer, its more for to give a frontend feel to the script imo. 
I found [anvil.works](https://anvil.works/) ...100% python fullstack web app builder/libraries, and yday I shot a question to them in re to libraries in my script to know which issues I could expect, and it was the founder, Meredydd Luff, that replied and answered my question. I would suggest looking into anvil.works if your concern is security of your notebook after sharing.